# firing event on selection of radio button

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm building a little js quiz game. With the code below, the user selects an answer and then has to click the answer button to submit, which checks whether the answer was correct. In other words, there's two steps. First, select. Second, submit. I wanted to know if there's a way to eliminate the second step, so that the event's fired on selection.

Here's a fiddle if necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/D5H9z/

I guess I don't know how to make a general event for all the select boxes that initiates the check, but then, at the same time, is able to inspect the selection to see if it's correct, if that makes any sense.

Note, the game is eventually going to be using something like Underscore templates to insert questions and answer choices into the fields, so if that influences how you'd set things up, please take it into consideration.

Thank you in advance

**html**

```
 <fieldset id="question1">
        <legend>What is the answer to this question?</legend>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="right"> Right answer</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="wrong"> Wrong answer</label>
            <ul>

    </fieldset>

            <input type="button" id="answer">
```

**js**

```
 document.getElementById("answer").onclick = validate;
    function validate() {
            var radios;
            var i;
            var right;
            radios = document.getElementById("question1").getElementsByTagName("input");

            right = false;
            for(i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
                    if(radios[i].value == "right" && radios[i].checked == true) {
                          right = true;
                    }
            }

            if(right) {
                    alert("You answered correctly");
            } else {
                    alert("Wrong answer");
            }
    }
```

**Update,** the final version of the game will be using Backbone, which supports events like this

```
events:{ 'click #sayhello': 'validate'
    },
```

The first two answers to this question proposed an 'inline' solution, but I was hoping for something that would fit in with backbone's event handling. What would I replace `#sayhello` with in order to trigger the validate function in this code.

Comment: If you're using backbone.js, and you want an answer that leverages backbone, why didn't you mention it in your post?  Why didn't you tag your question w/ backbone?

Comment: the general principle would be the same, with or without the backbone tag, I just wanted to know if there was one selector that I could use to trigger the validate event, without having a specific button that requires including a second step for the user (i.e. select, and then submit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply an `onclick` handler to each radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="right" onclick="validate">
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/D5H9z/)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want something inline like this. I updated the OP. Can you suggest what I would put in the place of #sayhello (to trigger the validate function) with the new code I provided

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<fieldset id="question1">
    <legend>What is the answer to this question?</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="right" onclick="javascript:check('right')"/> Right answer</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="wrong" onclick="javascript:check('wrong')"/> Wrong answer</label>


<script>
    function check(answer){
        alert(answer+" answer");
    }

</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D5H9z/3/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want something inline like this. I updated the OP. Can you suggest what I would put in the place of #sayhello (to trigger the validate function) with the new code I provided

Comment: How is this different from my answer, aside from the unnecessary `javascript:` preceeding the function call?